# Transistor action, transistor as an amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier

On Using the transistor as amplifier,  does the Current Gain stay constant by changing base current or R base?

Comment: this seems like a fun one, the beta dc aspects. I'll have to dig out my paper I wrote many years ago so I can show you that dc beta is not a constant. you see there are things physically aspects that are hard to explain on paper. I'll have to find my derivative formulas to explain the temperature and intrinsic resistance aspects. That is why (if you guys did a lab)  physical  measurements vs calculations are approximate.

Answer (score 1):

The current gain of a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) (one that has a collector, base and emitter) is the ratio of collector current (Ic) to base current (Ib) when it's not saturated. For most BJTs, it varies sufficiently slowly with current that it's worth giving it the name 'current gain'. It is also called beta, and hFE.

For typical BJTs, the beta is substantially constant (within a factor of 2 or so) over a large range of Ic from around 0.1% to 10% of rated Ic, in other words the useful or intended operating range of any given transistor. It tends to fall quickly in the top decade of rated Ic. There is also a strong temperature dependence of beta on the device temperature.

Comment: FETs are transistors too.

Comment: @ThePhoton FETs don't have current gain, so given the context, he's obviously referring to BJTs. Both he and I refer to a base terminal, what FETs did you have in mind that have a base?

Comment: I know you know that. And OP might even know that. But not every future reader will. We see enough questions ask that show many learners don't realize BJTs are only one of the possible kinds of transistor that it's worth clarifying.

Comment: In addition to Neil`s explanation I like to  mention that in electronics there is no single parameter or property which remains constant if one or more of the operating conditions is altered. The main question is always: Is there a large change or a "small" change only (small means: within acceptable tolerance limits)

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you mean by "R base." But the input impedance characteristics of the base do not change very much at all. The current flowing into the base programs the collector/emitter voltage/current relationship. So I would say that beta is enforced by changing the collector to emitter characteristics. Not by doing anything to the base.

The base current is like the accelerator pedal in your car. When you drive up a hill, the pedal does not push up against your foot harder. The pedal is in charge, and when you push it down, the car speeds up.

Let us consider a transistor operating in a steady state with 1mA of base current and 100mA of collector current (Beta = 100). If you attempt to increase the base current to 1.1mA, you will find that this is very easy to do and will not change the base voltage much at all. The voltage at the collector, however, will drop rapidly until the collector current increases to 110mA, or until the collector voltage is lower than the base. Whichever comes first. Hardly anything in electronics is more responsive than a BJT operating in its linear region this way.

But if you try to increase the collector current to 110mA, the collector voltage will rise very rapidly indeed, and the base will never know the difference. So to speak. (I am ignoring the Miller effect which you can learn about later).

So the base current is like a servo-control that lets you change a much larger current with impressive command authority.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand how exactly a BJT works you have to think of it as a voltage controlled current source not a current controlled source.

This means that the base-emitter voltage is what determines the collector current.Base current is just a deviation from being ideal.Actually base current is not what determines the collector current.As mentioned earlier.

You cannot depend on this relationship  Ic = HF*Ib.When designing transistor amplifiers any design that depends primarily on Beta is not a good one.Since HF is far from being constant.It depends on many parameters like temperature,collector current,collector-emitter voltage and so on.

One reason to convince yourself with the fact that Beta is not fairly constant is by looking at any BJT's datasheet.What you will find that Beta is given at various collector currents and assuming a certain temperature(usually 25 degrees) and fixed collector-emitter voltage.

More than that if all the previous parameters agrees with what given in the datasheet,Beta is given as a range not a single value because various transistors of the same type will have different beta values.

So one may ask "So if the DC current gain is quite unpredictable.Why it's so important BJT parameter?"

As said in previous answers most electronic devices' parameters cannot be reliably assumed constant over a wide range of variations in surroundings and circuit parameters.But as long as we can design circuits that reduces the dependence on these parameters and as long as we can do good approximations.We can depend on them but with some limitations and caution so that bizarre behaviour is avoided.